# Pushforward of measures with Fourier decay

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, harmonic-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

Suppose $\gamma: [0,1]^d \to \mathbf{R}^{d+1}$ is a smooth map with nonvanishing Gaussian curvature, and $\mu$ is a probability measure compactly supported on $(0,1)^d$ such that $|\widehat{\mu}(\xi)| \lesssim |\xi|^{-\alpha/2}$. Can one use this bound to obtain some decay of the form
$$ \int_{[0,1]^d} e^{-2 \pi i \eta \cdot \gamma(x)} d\mu(x) \lesssim |\eta|^{-\beta/2}$$
for $|\eta| \in \mathbf{R}^{d+1}$, as $|\eta| \to \infty$, which one can view as the Fourier coefficients of the probability measure $\gamma_* \mu$ in $\mathbf{R}^{d+1}$? Are there papers in the literature studying this type of situation?